# How to get this to print to the outfile? (c++)

Tags: c++, fstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   bool done = false;
   cout << setprecision(20) << endl;
    ifstream infile("in.txt");
    ifstream outfile("out.txt");
    while(!infile.eof()) {
           int sign = 1;
           double pi = 0;
           long n;
           infile >> n;

           for(long i = 1; i < n; i += 2) {
               pi += sign/(double)i;
               sign = -sign;
           }
           pi *= 4;
           cout << "value of pi for n = " << n << " is " << pi << endl;

       }


   return 0;
}
```

This reads from a file and prints to the console but I can't get the code to print to the outfile. I've tried doing

`outfile<< "value of pi for n = " << n << " is " << pi << endl;`

But that doesn't seem to work

Comment: you should define "ofstream" outfile("out.txt");  instead of  "ifstream" outfile("out.txt");

Comment: You will want to review [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Answer (score 1):

It does not write to the file because you defined `outfile` as an `std::ifstream`
`ifstream` is for input files.
Define it as an `ofstream` and it should work.

Example:

```cpp
ofstream outfile("out.txt");
```